# How can I plug config.json back into http://getbootstrap.com/customize?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I used http://getbootstrap.com/customize to build a customised colour scheme and the like and then downloaded the .zip using the button at the bottom of the page.

I see there's a config.json in that .zip; how do I plug that back into http://getbootstrap.com/customize if I want to further customise my bootstrap setup at a later date?

Answer (score 2):

The Bootstrap Customizer currently lacks that feature. It's an open feature request:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11004

That said, if you note the URL that your browser navigates to after clicking the "Compile and Download" button (e.g. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=9652496), going back to that URL later will auto-load your settings. There's another open issue about having the Customizer include that URL in the generated files; see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9951